# Rails display data with specific field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to display records that have a specific values in one of the fields.

**controller**

```
def mini
    @gears = Gear.where("Lab like ?", "%Mini%")
  end
```

The above code displays every record with the value "Mini" in the "Lab" field. I am now trying to make it so it displays records with two different values "Mini" and "Primary". So it would show me all records that have either "Mini" or "Primary" in the lab field.

I tried this

```
def mini
    @gears = Gear.where("Lab like ? AND Lab like ?","%Mini%", "%Primary%) 
  end
```

but it did not work. No error is thrown but no records are displayed on my front end webpage. I have also tried different variations but still no luck. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `OR` instead of `AND`.
use this `Gear.where("Lab like ? OR Lab like ?","%Mini%", "%Primary%)`

Comment: wow can't believe I didn't think of that. Worked like a charm thanks for your help @AshutoshTiwari

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for Scopes.  See this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

So in your gear.rb model file, do something like:

```
scope :mini, -> { where(lab: 'Mini') }
scope :primary, -> { where(lab: 'Primary') }
```

Then in your contorller, you could do:

```
@gears = Gear.mini #mini gears
```

or

```
@gears = Gear.primary #primary gears
```

or

```
@gears = Gear.mini.primary #mini and primary gears
```

Comment: The risk of using scopes here is that if no records match the criteria, all Gear records are returned.

Comment: Using `Gear.mini.primary` will not combine the conditions with a logic or but with an `AND`, therefor no result at all can be returned with `Gear.mini.primary`

Comment: Ashutosh's answer worked but I believe your answer @aspencer8111 could work as a solution for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494696/sunspot-solr-search-through-data-with-specific-field-value if you could take a look at it and give your thoughts please

Comment: Yes. Because the scopes chain using "AND", MrYoshiji is right and you are right on that answer working for your other Stackoverflow quesiton.